# How to programmatically restart a workflow

Tags: workflow, splistitem, tasks

I have a workflow linked to my list. Is there any programmatically way to select a list item and restart the associated workflow?

Something like:

```
SPListItem item = List.Items.GetById(1);
item.Workflows[GUID].Restart();
```

Is there any other way to get the same result?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of the Bruce answer is that if the workflow is already started if throws an exption..

To fix this I modified his code, checking and removing the Workflow if there is!

```
   private static void RestartWorkflow(SPListItem listItem, string workflowName)
    {
        SPWorkflowAssociation wfAssoc = listItem.ParentList.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName(workflowName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 
        var WF = listItem.Workflows.Cast<SPWorkflow>().Where(X => X.ParentAssociation.Name == "Flusso di gestione delle informazioni"); //My wf name
        if (WF.Any()) //if there is remove
        {
            listItem.Web.Site.WorkflowManager.RemoveWorkflowFromListItem(WF.First());
        } //start
        listItem.Web.Site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(listItem, wfAssoc, wfAssoc.AssociationData, true);
    }
```

Comment: Are you all sure? You're passing in wfAssoc.AssociationData as eventData? wfAssoc is actually association data. Any way to get the Initiation data to re-send it to workflow?

Comment: The only thing I know is that the code I posted works for a couple of custom workflow I written.. I dont' know if there are more specific way to do that.. If there are please post an anwser so I can accept a better one!

Answer (score 6):

SharePoint does not provide a method of restarting a workflow.  You can however cancel a running workflow and start it again.  A good example of canceling a running workflow can be found here: http://blog.brianfarnhill.com/2008/10/how-to-cancel-a-workflow-programmatically

The snippit of code below will start your workflow.

```
private static void StartWorkflow(SPListItem listItem, string workflowName)
{
    // Get the workflow by name that's associated with the list item
    SPWorkflowAssociation wfAssoc = listItem.ParentList.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName(workflowName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    // Start the workflow
    listItem.Web.Site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(listItem, wfAssoc, wfAssoc.AssociationData, true);
    listItem.Update();
}
```

Comment: Hi Bruce, could you add an explanation of your code please, just to make it a complete answer. Also please read the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq) for a guide on how to answer questions. Working together we can make this a better place :)

Comment: Exception generated from your code: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8102009B .. Any suggestion?

Comment: The exception you are receiving appears to be the result of a permissions issue.  The account your code is running under may not have permissions to the list item.

Comment: Mmm but I'm System Account, admin running code in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges..

Comment: If you're still receiving the error while running with elevated privileges, check that your reference to the web object was created within your elevated privileges block.

Answer (score 0):

If you use reusable Workflow. 
Change "...listItem.ParentList.WorkflowAssociations..." to
"...listItem.ContentType.WorkflowAssociations..."