# How to send email at specific time everyday in Sharepoint workflow?

Tags: 2013, workflow, email

[image]

This the current workflow I've made for my sharepoint. How do I edit the workflow such that I can email the Manager at 8am everyday? Do I have to add a loop somewhere, or a condition?

Answer (score 4):

There is way of doing it but it will pause your workflow for 24 hours everyday.

In my workflow, I have taken three stages.

1. We check the condition for entering into the workflow and pause for
   the next day and send the email at 8 AM and pass it to stage 2.
2. We pause the workflow for next 24 hours and pass it to stage 3.
3. We send the mail and pass the state to stage 2.

Here is what I have created.
[image]
I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! May I know where I can find the "Go to next step" action? I can't find it under "Actions" (using sharepoint 2013 by the way). I tried googling, but can't find any good tutorials to understand how to make that.

Comment: If you are seeing Transition to stage. Click on the line and then you will find go to in action.

Comment: My sharepoint doesn't have the "transition to stage" feature. Are there any alternatives you may know of to move to the next stage?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Workflow 2013 or Workflow 2010?

Comment: Hi I'm using workflow 2010.

Comment: If you are using Workflow 2013, you will find the option as I have used in the above answer. If you can try with 2013 workflow it will work.

Comment: The 2013 workflow needs to be configured on your sharepoint farm. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 3):

if you are using On Premise version of SharePoint, Please follow the below steps

1. Create a powershell script file to run the workflow against all
   items. please find the sample below

> ```
>   $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "https://yoursite/sitetest"
>   $manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager
>   $list = $web.Lists["List Name"]
>   $assoc = 
>   $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("WorkflowName","en-US")
>   $data = $assoc.AssociationData 
>   $items = $list.Items 
>   foreach($item in $items)  
>   {  
>   $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data,$true)  
>   }
>   $manager.Dispose()
>   $web.Dispose()
> ```

2. Create a task in task schedular that runs everyday at 8 AM.
3. Create a new action to start a program.
4. In Program/script,please enter powershell.exe -file "path of
   powershell script created in step 1"

if you are using Online version of SharePoint, Please follow the below steps

1. Create a console application in c# to start a workflow against all
   items. please find the sample below

> [How to programmatically restart a workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53272/how-to-programmatically-restart-a-workflow)

2. Create a task in task schedular that runs everyday at 8 AM.
3. Create a new action to start a program.
4. In Program/script,please enter the path of exe file generated from
   console application.

Hope this helps.
Thank You.